# The bare minimum smartctl command to check disk health

Tags: smartmontools

Is the command like the one below enough to periodically check the health of a disk?

```
smartctl -H /dev/sda
```

The output contains a line like the one below.

```
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
```

But what is a "self-assessment test"? Is that result up-to-date at the time I execute the command?

In other words, should I rather ask for an extended test with "-t short" or "-t long" and then retrieve the needed information with "smartctl -l selftest /dev/sda"?

All I need is knowing when an hard disk has to be replaced without going to check a LED on the cabinet of the physical machine.

I tried to have a look at the documentation of "smartmontools", but I'm still lost there and I feel under pressure.

Thanks in advance!

Andrea

Answer (score 1):

You may take a fast look at the examples section of the man page.

SMART does test on the fly, not directly visible to the operating system, when ordered to do so - otherwise, SMART will just do some basic tests. But the overall default configuration is dependent on what the manufacturer of your hard drive / solid state drive / tape drive has implemented.

Keep in mind, when you order SMART to do some self test, this will use internal I/O operations of the drive. Meaning, if you order your drive to do a long self test, your drives performances will be slower than usual, cause your drive is performing the physical self test, checking block after block...

So long-self-tests should not be done every time, as they reduce performance of your drive, while test is going on.

Commands you issue to your SMART capable drives via smartctl are valid until otherwise commanded or after full system power off (meaning, issued commands might survive a soft reset of the machine).

I recommend using default auto settings of your drives.

At system boot, you once tell your drives to start periodicly scans in an automated way, you can do this via:

```
smartctl --smart=on --offlineauto=on --saveauto=on /dev/sda
```

This will start to perform several, regular and periodic tests, in a performances friendly fashion for drive `/dev/sda` in background (not directly visible to the operating system).

Then you can check the health of your drive using the command `smartctl -H /dev/sda`, or `smartctl --health /dev/sda`. If this command returns an error, this usually means that either the drive is already in failure or the drive is predicting to go into failure within the next 24 hours. So performing a periodic check of at least every 12 hours is recommended. When a failure has been found, you can use `smartctl -a /dev/sda` or `smartctl --all /dev/sda` for more info. Usual, you don't need to check more often than for every 4 hours. As the automated scans probably will only run every 4 hours (but this depends on the manufacturers default settings).

PS Linux machines usually have already an automated SMART check enabled, using a daemon (service), often just named as `smartd.service`. You can check it's status via `systemctl status smartd.service` and/or watch its logs via `journalctl --unit smartd.service`

Comment: Thanks, @paladin! Though I still cannot tell what is the bare minimum I should do to have the information equivalent to the information of a lit-up failure LED, in case there's a failure. You wrote "SMART does test on the fly, not directly visible to the operating system, when ordered to do so - otherwise, SMART will just do some basic tests". Would the basic tests be enough for my aim? If that is the case how can I ask for basic tests? A command like "smartctl -H /dev/sda" would be enough or it is just to know the result of some test requested beforehand?

Comment: You wrote "As the automated scans probably will only run every 4 hours (but this depends on the manufacturers default settings)". I'm confused. I cannot even tell whether scans are performed necessarily as a consequence of an explicit request with a command or, instead, the hardware will refresh the information anyway, and, if that is the case, with what frequency - where does that "4 hours" come from?

Comment: It's the default setting for most SMART drives. How about you just try the command `smartctl --smart=on --offlineauto=on --saveauto=on /dev/sda`, you'll see that it will tell you that it will run scans every 4 hours.

Comment: The basic test is just some kind of simple power on self test + runtime tests. Also the drive will report problems which it will find while usual operations. You can just use `smartctl -H /dev/sda`, but this will only report currently found problems. Your drive could have bad sectors, where you don't know that it has bad sectors, cause you are not using the sectors, that's why you should perform regular tests to check also the unused sectors. Most errors on a drive are being detected by trying to read the bad sectors. If you are not reading, you cannot detect bad sectors.

Comment: Thanks, @paladin. If I got it correctly, basic tests do not include any scan for finding badblocks and are performed anyway, no matter what has been scheduled with /etc/smartd.conf. Can you confirm? Now the problem is I get different outputs to the command `smartctl --smart=on --offlineauto=on --saveauto=on [device references]`, depending on the disk I specify. I have to check seven disk distributed in two different RAID combination (probably one is RAID 1 and the other is RAID 5). But I'm afraid to effectively explain I have to do a separate request for help...

Comment: Please have a look... https://serverfault.com/questions/1155257/issues-reading-outputs-with-different-raid-configurations Thanks in advance!

Comment: SMART depends on the firmware of the drive. Also SMART is not 100% bulletproof.

Comment: it turned out that three disk are SAS, not SATA as the other two. Still I don't know how in the case of SAS disks I can get a synthetic information about the health of the disk after a short or after a long scan. Perhaps a `smartctl -H` is enough in that case? What do you mean with "bulletproof" in this case, anyway? Thanks!