# Issues reading outputs with different disk types (SATA and SAS)

Tags: smartmontools

The output of a `smartctl --scan` follows.

```
/dev/sda -d scsi # /dev/sda, SCSI device
/dev/sdb -d scsi # /dev/sdb, SCSI device
/dev/bus/2 -d megaraid,0 # /dev/bus/2 [megaraid_disk_00], SCSI device
/dev/bus/2 -d megaraid,1 # /dev/bus/2 [megaraid_disk_01], SCSI device
/dev/bus/2 -d megaraid,2 # /dev/bus/2 [megaraid_disk_02], SCSI device
/dev/bus/2 -d megaraid,3 # /dev/bus/2 [megaraid_disk_03], SCSI device
/dev/bus/2 -d megaraid,4 # /dev/bus/2 [megaraid_disk_04], SCSI device
```

This is the result related to **five disks**. I don't know if I can check what are the RAID configurations involved from the operating system, I suppose I can't, anyway at the moment I cannot deal with the BIOS.
I suppose the first two disks are in a RAID 1 configuration (they are seen as /dev/sda) and the other three disks are in a RAID 5 configuration (they are seen as /dev/sdb).

The problem is **I usually get different outputs from similar commands, depending whether they refer disk to the first RAID configuration or to the second RAID configuration**.

For example with the command
`smartctl --smart=on --offlineauto=on --saveauto=on /dev/bus/2 -d megaraid,0` I get the following output.

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-155-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF ENABLE/DISABLE COMMANDS SECTION ===
SMART Enabled.
SMART Attribute Autosave Enabled.
SMART Automatic Offline Testing Enabled every four hours.
```

Instead with the command `smartctl --smart=on --offlineauto=on --saveauto=on /dev/bus/2 -d megaraid,2` I get the following output.

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-155-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF ENABLE/DISABLE COMMANDS SECTION ===
Informational Exceptions (SMART) enabled
Temperature warning enabled
Autosave enabled (GLTSD bit cleared).
```

Actually I'm not getting what above is mentioned as the frequency of "Automatic Offline Testing".

I've a similar issue when I try to see the result after a short scan or after a long scan.

With `smartctl -l error /dev/bus/2 -d megaraid,0`...

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-155-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged
```

With `smartctl -l error /dev/bus/2 -d megaraid,2`, instead...

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-155-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
Error counter log:
           Errors Corrected by           Total   Correction     Gigabytes    Total
               ECC          rereads/    errors   algorithm      processed    uncorrected
           fast | delayed   rewrites  corrected  invocations   [10^9 bytes]  errors
read:   3595257651        0         0  3595257651          0       1843.590           0
write:         0        0         0         0          0       3076.669           0
verify: 3551761787        0         0  3551761787          0      15017.264           0

Non-medium error count:      372
```

And really here I feel kind of lost...

Similarly, with `smartctl -l selftest /dev/bus/2 -d megaraid,0`...

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-155-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     59961         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     59937         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     59913         -
# 4  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     59897         -
# 5  Extended offline    Aborted by host               70%     59895         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     59889         -
# 7  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     59837         -
# 8  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     59339         -
# 9  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     59336         -
#10  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     37147         -
#11  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     37147         -
#12  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     37147         -
#13  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     37146         -
#14  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     37146         -
#15  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     37146         -
```

And with `smartctl -l selftest /dev/bus/2 -d megaraid,2`...

```
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log
Num  Test              Status                 segment  LifeTime  LBA_first_err [SK ASC ASQ]
     Description                              number   (hours)
# 1  Background short  Completed                   -   60525                 - [-   -    -]
# 2  Background short  Completed                   -   60501                 - [-   -    -]
# 3  Background long   Completed                   -   60482                 - [-   -    -]
# 4  Background short  Completed                   -   60477                 - [-   -    -]
# 5  Background short  Completed                   -   60468                 - [-   -    -]
# 6  Background short  Aborted (by user command)   -   60468                 - [-   -    -]
# 7  Background long   Aborted (by user command)   -   60458                 - [-   -    -]
# 8  Background long   Aborted (by user command)   -   60458                 - [-   -    -]
# 9  Background short  Completed                   -   60453                 - [-   -    -]
#10  Background short  Completed                   -   59897                 - [-   -    -]
#11  Background short  Completed                   -   37513                 - [-   -    -]
#12  Background short  Completed                   -   37513                 - [-   -    -]
#13  Background short  Completed                   -   37513                 - [-   -    -]
#14  Background short  Completed                   -   37513                 - [-   -    -]
#15  Background short  Completed                   -   37513                 - [-   -    -]
#16  Background short  Completed                   -   37513                 - [-   -    -]

Long (extended) Self-test duration: 65535 seconds [1092.2 minutes]
```

Actually **in the second case I cannot tell if the outcome of the completed tests is an OK or not**...

Besides I found several "short tests" I felt not responsible for (I didn't remeber I launched so many `smartctl -t short`). In the default configuration for smartd coming with the smartmontools package I found the following line.

```
DEVICESCAN -d removable -n standby -m root -M exec /usr/share/smartmontools/smartd-runner
```

How can this line be responsibile for all the short tests I found about? I see no request for a scan there. Am I wrong?

I've been told periodically basic tests are performed anyway, because they are programmed in the hardware, but they do not include any check for badblocks. As you can read above, I had a trouble in getting the frequency of those test for the disks in the supposed RAID 5 configuration.

I'm sorry for the long message, unfortunately my case seems more complicated if compared with the typical examples in the documents I can find in the Internet...

Would you please help me in understanding how I can interpret the information I have available in my case?

Thanks in advance!

Andrea

**--- UPDATE ---**
As suggested in a comment below, it's not a matter of RAID configuration, but of different disks. Two of them are SATA and the other three are SAS.

I check the first one with `smartctl -i /dev/bus/2 -d megaraid,0`...

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-155-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Caviar Green
Device Model:     WDC WD5000AADS-00S9B0
Serial Number:    WD-WCAV9V055931
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 159e577d2
Firmware Version: 01.00A01
User Capacity:    500.107.862.016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Tue Feb 27 18:27:38 2024 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

I check the first one with `smartctl -i /dev/bus/2 -d megaraid,2`...

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-155-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               SEAGATE
Product:              ST1000NM0045
Revision:             N002
Compliance:           SPC-4
User Capacity:        1.000.204.886.016 bytes [1,00 TB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
LU is fully provisioned
Rotation Rate:        7200 rpm
Form Factor:          3.5 inches
Logical Unit id:      0x5000c500856f8ae7
Serial number:        ZBS00JGK0000R639QNRU
Device type:          disk
Transport protocol:   SAS (SPL-3)
Local Time is:        Tue Feb 27 18:30:35 2024 CET
SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is:     Enabled
Temperature Warning:  Enabled
```

**The problem remains: how can I read the output data in the case of the SAS disks?**

Comment: What disks are there? The `smartctl` output for SATA and SAS disks differs substantially. Attach, for example, `smarctl -i /dev/bus/2 -d megaraid,0` and `smarctl -i /dev/bus/2 -d megaraid,4`, or other. NB: to see RAID controller configuration, status and to set it up from the OS you need to use `megacli` or `storcli` utility, and the number after `megaraid,` actually refer to the in-controller device index that you will use with these utilities to address that drive.

Comment: @Nikita Kipriyanov, thanks! I updated the post - please, have a look at the update - and the title. Though I still have to figure out how to get with SAS disks the same information I get with the SATA disks...

Comment: The RAID controller itself performs so called "patrol reads" and "consistency checks" periodically, by default it's every other week AFAIK. So twice per month every disk is read and if there is any problem it is kicked out of the array, at which point the RAID becomes degraded and the controller should alert you. It will typically beep, but to receive an alert remotely you need to poll the controller for the state. So, suggested `megacli` or `storcli` is not optional; it's mandatory as it is necessary to monitor everything from the OS. Does not answer the question, but related and very useful.

Comment: So I usually rely on HW controller's patrol reads and consistency checks or (in case of software RAID) the cron jobs for mdadm's "check" runs, which is the same thing as HW RAID consistency check, and then use smartctl only to see the number of remapped sectors ("elements in a grown defect list" for SAS). And the monitoring system alerts me if the number increases (or something else happens, e.g. degraded array). The built-in selftests are inconvenient for this.

Comment: Many thanks, Nikita, for your view. I've installed storcli, though so far I could just view the RAID configuration, made at hardware level.
What would be the storcli command to check whether there's a hardware alarm due to some faulty disk?
Besides, I've been warned about the importance of possible bad blocks, and so about the importance of smartctl scans... Please, have a look at the post at the following URL.
https://serverfault.com/questions/1152562/the-bare-minimum-smartctl-command-to-check-disk-health

Comment: Though I cannot tell whether a scan includes also the solutions for possible bad blocks - presumably it doesn't - and I still cannot interpret the output of "smartctl -l selftest" and "smartctl -l error" for SAS disks. Can you please suggest me the tried-and-tested storcli and smartctl commands useful to send an automated report via email in case of failure?

Comment: They don't send reports. You need to write the script that would interpret the output and act accordingly; I was using Zabbix, (made a UserParameter script for its agent), and the server was in turn sending alerts. Here's [a StorCli manual](https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/12352476); for example, `storcli /c0/sall show` would show a table with all drives together with their status, which you parse and see if any drives show problems. As for `smartctl`, `smartcl -A /dev/... -d megaraid,ID` will show the most useful metrics, albeit in a different way for SATA HDDs, SSDs and SAS.

Comment: Also useful: `storcli /c0/v0 show all` (you need to issue it for each VD, e.g. v0, v1, v2...), will show the RAID state of that LD, e.g. whether it is degraded, or spare is in use, etc. That is enough for monitoring. // Want to apologize in advance: I can't share my Zabbix script. I don't own it, it is the property of my (past) employer. However, it is not that hard to write such a script.